# How to get execution time of a specific script that is running, but in the background?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I have a script (php) that runs in the background (`nohup php script...`), but for some reason it ends up stopping, as this script only produces 'logs' when it has something to do.

I need 'something' to know how long it was running until the moment it stopped , but I didn't want to let the responsibility for this script to 'make log' every second, I'd like some way to see how long time it was running, but so that I can "close the all terminal" screens and when reconnecting to the terminal, I can query the stop time, or even the execution time and time the script stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add execution time `nohup` log by execution the command on this way:

```
nohup /usr/bin/time php script...
```